# check to see if xml exists (not working)

Tags: php, xml

i am trying to check through php if xml files exists on a url (incremental names till it fails)

why is this code not working?

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$url = "http://thetvdb.com/api/E676DF9578EF38D7/series/78901/default/".$i."/1/en.xml";
echo $url."<br />";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

if ($xml) {
echo "yay"."<br />";
} else {
echo "fail"."<br />";
die();
}
}



?>
```

Comment: Please define *"not working"*

Comment: `die()` breaks the loop and exits your code. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is `die()`. This quits all execution.

I'd also try using `fopen()` instead of `simplexml_load_file()` unless you plan on using the XML later on, eg

```
$handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
if ($handle === false) {
    echo 'fail<br />';
    return; // check till it fails
} else {
    echo 'yay<br />';
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use curl to find out whether a file exists:

```
function does_remote_file_exist($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($code == 200) $status = true;
    else $status = false;

    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}
```